# Over-ride default Satchmo email with custom template

Tags: python, django, satchmo

I'm using [Satchmo](http://www.satchmoproject.com/) for the shop section of a website. I'm trying to override the default 'order_complete' email with my own, but haven't been able to so far. The [docs](http://www.satchmoproject.com/docs/dev/customization.html) indicate that it should be done in the same way as overriding any other template. So I've created one in my template folder at shop/email/order_complete.html, but it isn't being picked up. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but, is Satchmo listed in installed_apps before your own app? (If so the order_complete template may be being matched before yours is ever reached.)

Try moving your app before Satchmo and see if that solves it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I moved all of the Satchmo apps to the end of the INSTALLED_APPS list but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your template folder to take precedence over the app template folders, you have to set your `'django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source',` before the `app_directories` loader.

Comment: I haven't had the chance to try this out yet and probably won't be able to until tomorrow. I'll report back with the result.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: The same is the default setting for both Django and Satchmo. Currently it is `...filesystem.Loader` instead of '...filesystem.load_template_source' for Django 1.2 or 1.4